# HTTP to HTTPS redirection in asp.net not working

Tags: asp.net, https

We have a simple requirement to use https for certain specific pages in a asp.net 4.0 web application. For checking our implementation, we deployed a simple asp.net 4.0 app to IIS 7. The app has been coded to redirect the default.aspx page to securepage.aspx over https based on a web.config flag.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri requestUri = Page.Request.Url;
        UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder("https", requestUri.Host, requestUri.Port, "SecurePage.aspx");
        string secureUrl = builder.Uri.ToString();

        if (bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseSecure"]))
        {
            Response.Redirect(secureUrl, true);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write(secureUrl);
        }
    }
```

But after we deploy this app on IIS 7 and load the default.aspx page, it shows "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". But if we turn the config flag off, it displays the page properly. The app has http binding on port 82 and https on port 444.

Can anybody point me in where we are going wrong.

Comment: witch of the two answer is the one that work, the one with `http` or the one with `https` ? or both ? because the answers have this small diferent.

Comment: Both of them will work depending on what is required. The main point was about the https port being same as the http request port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type in front `https` then the browser is go on port `443` and not on 444, so to movit on your custom port you need to type it as.

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder("http", requestUri.Host, 444, "SecurePage.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the current request's port via requestUri.Port, which returns 80.  You should hard-code the 444 instead:

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder("https", requestUri.Host, 444, "SecurePage.aspx");
```

Or use a configurable variable if the port changes.